# sf + ggplot trying to map Fiji Islands

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am working to help a fellow R user to figure out this issue. I wrote a sf+ ggplot tutorial (https://www.r-spatial.org//r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf) and I'm trying to help someone figure out how to plot Fiji islands correctly. I've been trying with manipulating the xlim and ylim, but it's not wrapping around the world correctly (because of the coordinates being so close to "0") to show all of the islands. If any one has any insights on a way to get around this, that would be greatly appreciated and I can add the code to the tutorial for the future. Thank you!

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data=world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim= c(175, 180), ylim=c(-20,-12.0), expand = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when working with `geom_sf()`, you should always specify an appropriate coordinate reference system (CRS). This will make better maps, and it will also fix issues such as the one you're encountering. In this specific case, since you want to plot Fiji, you should use a Fiji-specific CRS, e.g. this one: https://epsg.io/3460

The plot limits in the `coord_sf()`call are taken from the projected bounds available at the same web site.

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data=world) +
  geom_sf() + 
  coord_sf(
    crs = 3460, # https://epsg.io/3460
    xlim = c(1798028.61, 2337149.40), # limits are taken from projected bounds
    ylim = c(3577110.39, 4504717.19)  # of EPSG:3460
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>